# Prevent Mavericks from generating new volume name for external drive

Tags: hard-drive, external-disk, mount, automount

I have an external HDD, formatted exFAT, I believe. Whenever it is re-mounted, it gets assigned a new volume name (e.g., "MyVolume", "MyVolume 1", "MyVolume 2"...). As far as I can tell, this happens whether it is properly ejected, or if it is still mounted when the system is powered down.

Aside from going in to /Volumes/ and deleting all the existing "MyVolume*" files before attempting to mount the drive, is there a way to prevent this from happening?

Answer (score 1):

Question re-asked because of lack of input.
Got some clues. Found answer related on discussion of ntfs-3g (though problem was not related to ntfs mounting).
See https://github.com/osxfuse/osxfuse/issues/119

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. 
Please take a look here too: http://apple.stackexchange.com/help/deleted-answers